# Sign raw transaction with key

Tags: bitcoin-core, signrawtransaction

I'm upgrading my application from bitcoin core 21.0 to 23.0.

In core 21.0 I created a raw transaction and sign it with my private key after I called `dumpprivkey` RPC. At core 23.0 I received this error when I Called `dumpprivkey`:

`This type of wallet does not support this command`

How can I sign my transaction with my private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's currently not possible to export private keys from descriptor wallets.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/107956/5406)

I don't think you needed to dump the key first in the first place, though. As far as I can tell, `signrawtransactionwithwallet` should do exactly what you're looking for.