# Private key problem, getting an error (code -4) please help

Tags: private-key

im trying to get my private key, i did wallet passphrase 600, got null response, did dumpprivkey "wallet" and i get
￼
This type of wallet does not support this command (code -4)

anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does this help: [How do I get the private key of an address in descriptor wallets? How to dumpprivkey?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/107216/13866)

Comment: Hi @StaciCosto, very likely you have created a descriptor wallet and are running into the issue that RedGrittyBrick suggested. If you find that it doesn't resolve your query, please update your question here and vote to reopen. Thanks!